# Как заблокировать горячую клавишу

Tags: python

Как с помощью питона заблокировать горячую клавишу?
Пробовал `keyboard.add_hotkey("alt + tab", lambda: None, suppress =True)` и `root.bind(<"alt + f4">, somefunction)`, но эти клавиши не блокируются. Помогите

Comment: что вы используете, чтобы получать нажатия клавиши? насколько я понимаю, вы не хотите получать информацию о нажатии некоторых клавиш?

Comment: @jediAllen Так они и не будут блокироваться. Ибо они обрабатываются в OS, а "блокируете" вы их в приложении. Хотя `Alt+F4` ещё вроде как можно забороть (см. [ответ здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358014/override-alt-f4-closing-tkinter-window-in-python-3-6-and-replace-it-with-somethi)), но вот `Alt+Tab` - вряд ли.